# Copying a video stream encoded with HEVC produces unplayable output. H264 works

Tags: delphi, winapi, ms-media-foundation

When I copy a video stream from a source-file to a target-file using a SourceReader and a SinkWriter, the target file is unplayable, if the source-video has been encoded with HEVC.

I've tried to create the smallest example to reproduce my problem. Written in Delphi, but should be easy enough to understand.

**Edit:** The media-foundation headers necessary to compile the code can be found at
https://github.com/FactoryXCode/MfPack

Steps to reproduce problem with the procedures below:
Create a video showing a blue frame encoded with HEVC:

```
WriteBlueMovie('MyVideoFile.mp4',MFVideoFormat_HEVC);
```

Copy the video stream to another file:

```
CopyVideoStream('MyVideoFile.mp4','MyFileCopy.mp4');
```

MyFileCopy contains a video stream, but the media-type info is missing. As a result it cannot be played. The same works, when MFVideoFormat_H264 is used instead.

Eventually I would like to expand CopyVideoStream to a muxer, so I need to copy the video stream sample by sample.

What can I do so the output file contains the correct stream header for the video stream?

Thanks in advance.

```
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  WinApi.Windows,
  Winapi.ActiveX,
  VCL.Dialogs,
  // mfPack headers
  Winapi.MediaFoundationApi.MfApi,
  Winapi.MediaFoundationApi.MfUtils,
  Winapi.MediaFoundationApi.MfReadWrite,
  Winapi.MediaFoundationApi.Mfobjects,
  Winapi.MediaFoundationApi.CodecApi,
  Winapi.ActiveX.PropIdl,
  Winapi.MediaFoundationApi.MfIdl;
procedure WriteBlueMovie(const OutputFile: string; Encoder: TGUID);
var
  pSinkWriter: IMFSinkWriter;
  Count: DWord;
  attribs: IMFAttributes;
  pMediaTypeOut, pMediaTypeIn: IMFMediaType;
  VideoStream: DWord;
  Time, Duration: int64;
  pBuffer: IMFMediaBuffer;
  BufferSize: DWord;
  BlueRef: DWord;
  pData: PByte;
  pSample: IMFSample;
  i: integer;
  PCR: PDWord;
  hrCoInit: HResult;
const
  Blue: TRGBQuad = (rgbBlue: 255; rgbGreen: 0; rgbRed: 0; rgbReserved: 0);

const
  ProcName = 'WriteBlueMovie';
  //turn return of fail for HResult into exception
  procedure CheckFail(hr: HResult);
  begin
    inc(Count);
    if Failed(hr) then
    begin
      if succeeded(hrCoInit) then
        CoUninitialize;
      raise Exception.Create('Error in ' + ProcName + ' in call nr. ' +
        IntToStr(Count) + 'with error code $' + IntToHex(hr));
    end;
  end;

begin
  Count := 0;
  hrCoInit := CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
  CheckFail(hrCoInit);
  CheckFail(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));

  // Create attributes for the SinkWriter
  CheckFail(MFCreateAttributes(attribs, 4));
  CheckFail(attribs.SetUINT32(MF_READWRITE_ENABLE_HARDWARE_TRANSFORMS,
    UInt32(true)));
  // Enable quality based encoding
  CheckFail(attribs.SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonRateControlMode, 3));
  CheckFail(attribs.SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQuality, 70));
  CheckFail(attribs.SetUINT32(CODECAPI_AVEncCommonQualityVsSpeed, 70));
  // Create the SinkWriter
  CheckFail(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(PWideChar(OutputFile), nil, attribs,
    pSinkWriter));

  // Configure the output format
  CheckFail(MFCreateMediaType(pMediaTypeOut));
  CheckFail(pMediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));

  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  // Encoder = MFVideoFormat_H264 below will work for the copy, Encoder = MFVideoFormat_HEVC will not.
  CheckFail(pMediaTypeOut.SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, Encoder));
  // !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

  CheckFail(pMediaTypeOut.SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE,
    MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1));
  // force fixed frame rate
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut,
    MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN, 30, 1));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut,
    MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, 30, 1));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeOut, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));

  // Add stream to the sinkwriter
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.AddStream(pMediaTypeOut, VideoStream));

  // Configure the input format
  CheckFail(MFCreateMediaType(pMediaTypeIn));
  CheckFail(pMediaTypeIn.SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video));
  CheckFail(pMediaTypeIn.SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32));
  CheckFail(pMediaTypeIn.SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE,
    MFVideoInterlace_Progressive));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeSize(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 640, 480));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 30, 1));
  // force fixed frame rate
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn,
    MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MIN, 30, 1));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn,
    MF_MT_FRAME_RATE_RANGE_MAX, 30, 1));
  CheckFail(MFSetAttributeRatio(pMediaTypeIn, MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO, 1, 1));

  // Set the input format of the sinkwriter
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.SetInputMediaType(VideoStream, pMediaTypeIn, nil));

  // Timing
  Time := 0;
  // Duration of one frame in units of 100 Nanoseconds
  Duration := round(1000 * 10000 / 30);

  // Create a media buffer holding one blue frame
  BufferSize := 4 * 640 * 480;
  // Is this really necessary? I think not. A typecast DWord(Blue) does the same.
  CopyRgbQuadToClrRef(Blue, BlueRef);
  CheckFail(MFCreateMemoryBuffer(BufferSize, pBuffer));
  CheckFail(pBuffer.Lock(pData, nil, nil));
  PCR := PDWord(pData);
  for i := 1 to 640 * 480 do
  begin
    PCR^ := BlueRef;
    inc(PCR);
  end;
  CheckFail(pBuffer.Unlock);
  CheckFail(pBuffer.SetCurrentLength(BufferSize));

  // write 10 seconds of video
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.BeginWriting);
  while Time < 10 * 1000 * 10000 do
  begin
    CheckFail(MFCreateSample(pSample));
    CheckFail(pSample.AddBuffer(pBuffer));
    CheckFail(pSample.SetSampleTime(Time));
    CheckFail(pSample.SetSampleDuration(Duration));
    CheckFail(pSinkWriter.WriteSample(VideoStream, pSample));
    inc(Time, Duration);
  end;

  // Shut down
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.Finalize);
  CheckFail(MFShutdown);
  CoUninitialize;
end;

procedure CopyVideoStream(const InputFile, OutputFile: string);
var
  Count: integer;
  pSourceReader: IMFSourceReader;
  pSinkWriter: IMFSinkWriter;
  pMediaType: IMFMediaType;
  SourceStreamIndex, SinkStreamIndex: DWord;
  Done: boolean;
  pSample: IMFSample;
  flags: DWord;
  timestamp: int64;
  hrCoInit: HResult;
const
  ProcName = 'CopyVideoStream';
  procedure CheckFail(hr: HResult);
  begin
    inc(Count);
    if Failed(hr) then
    begin
      if succeeded(hrCoInit) then
        CoUninitialize;
      raise Exception.Create('Error in ' + ProcName + ' in call nr. ' +
        IntToStr(Count) + 'with error code $' + IntToHex(hr));
    end;
  end;

begin
  Count := 0;
  hrCoInit := CoInitializeEx(nil, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
  CheckFail(hrCoInit);
  CheckFail(MFStartup(MF_VERSION));

  // Create sourcereader for InputFile and sinkwriter for OutputFile
  CheckFail(MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(PWideChar(InputFile), nil,
    pSourceReader));
  CheckFail(MFCreateSinkWriterFromURL(PWideChar(OutputFile), nil, nil,
    pSinkWriter));

  // Get the media type of the 1st video stream
  CheckFail(pSourceReader.GetNativeMediaType
    (MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, pMediaType));
  CheckFail(pSourceReader.SetStreamSelection
    (MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, true));
  // Set this media type as the output format of the source reader, maybe not necessary.
  CheckFail(pSourceReader.SetCurrentMediaType
    (MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0, pMediaType));

  // Create stream in sinkwriter with the exact same mediatype
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.AddStream(pMediaType, SinkStreamIndex));
  // Set the same media type as input format, maybe not necessary;
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.SetInputMediaType(SinkStreamIndex, pMediaType, nil));

  //For debugging check the format of pMediaType. Always returns the correct result.
  var Encoder: TGUID;
  var EncoderName: string;
  CheckFail(pMediaType.GetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, Encoder));
  if Encoder=MFVideoFormat_H264 then
  EncoderName:='H264'
  else
  if Encoder=MFVideoFormat_HEVC then
  EncoderName:='HEVC'
  else
  EncoderName:='No Codec';
  ShowMessage('SinkWriter Encoding Format: '+EncoderName);


  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.BeginWriting());
  Done := false;
  // Loop to copy samples from source to sink
  while not Done do
  begin
    CheckFail(pSourceReader.ReadSample(MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_VIDEO_STREAM, 0,
      @SourceStreamIndex,
      // get actual index of the stream
      @flags, // get flags for this sample
      @timestamp, // get the timestamp for this sample
      @pSample) // get the actual sample
      );
    if (pSample <> nil) then
    begin
      // push the sample to the sink writer
      CheckFail(pSinkWriter.WriteSample(SinkStreamIndex, pSample));
    end
    else if ((flags and MF_SOURCE_READERF_STREAMTICK) <> 0) then
    begin
      // signal a stream tick
      CheckFail(pSinkWriter.SendStreamTick(SinkStreamIndex, timestamp));
    end;
    if ((flags and MF_SOURCE_READERF_ENDOFSTREAM) <> 0) then
    begin
      CheckFail(pSinkWriter.NotifyEndOfSegment(SinkStreamIndex));

      Done := true;
    end;
  end;

  // Shut Down
  CheckFail(pSinkWriter.Finalize);
  CheckFail(MFShutdown);
  CoUninitialize;
end;
```

Comment: Your "_smallest example to reproduce my problem_" misses all the types and/or the `uses` section, naming all the units hopefully everyone/every Delphi version has.

Comment: I edited my question. If this is not acceptable, I will remove the Delphi-tag. I cannot possibly include all those header files as source.